# Run a command for the nth target with the nth dependancy

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am having some confusion about how the '$<' and '$@' macros can be used with a list of elements. My ultimate goal is to compile a directory of C source files into executables with the same name, no extensions. Also I do not want to make object files.

Here is a simple makefile which I would like to upgrade using the macros.

```
CC = gcc -ansi -std=c99
CCFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -O3

all : progA progB progC

progA : progA.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< -o $@

progB : progB.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< -o $@

progC : progC.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

This works fine, but I don't like the redundancy of the commands. I have found a workaround that works, and a near solution, but was hoping there might be a clear option.

---

workaround:

```
CC = gcc -ansi -std=c99
CCFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -O3
PRGS := $(patsubst %.c,%,$(wildcard *.c))

all : 
    make $(PRGS)

% : *.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $@.c -o $@
```

What I don't like here is the call to make within the command. Running 'make' delivers a message in my terminal that looks something like this:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/path/to/dir'
...actual commands...
make[1]: Leaving directory '/path/to/dir'
```

I am assuming this has to do with opening the same makefile and the [1] refers to the second file descriptor in the open file table (or something along those lines).

---

near solution:

```
CC = gcc -ansi -std=c99
CCFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -O3
SRCS := $(wildcard *.c)
PRGS := $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SRCS))

all : $(PRGS)

$(PRGS) : $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

This almost works, except it is always grabbing the first dependancy!

```
..... progA.c -o progA
..... progA.c -o progB
..... progA.c -o progC
```

---

So, does anyone have a cleaner method to my 'workaround' or perhaps a solution to my 'near solution'? Is there anyway to match the nth target to the nth dependency when running the command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$(PRGS): $(SRCS)` change is just incorrect. It lists *every* source file as the prerequisites of *every* target.

You want to set the prerequisites of the `all` target to be every program you want built by default. To do that you want to use `all: $(PRGS)`. Not a recipe of calling make again like you had originally.

(If you did want to keep the manual recursive call to make you could use `make --no-print-directory` on that call to avoid the message but that is still the wrong approach (and if you were going to do that you'd want to use `$(MAKE)` to handle arguments to the original make correctly.)

A second problem with your original makefile is the use of `*.c` in the prerequisite list of the `%` target. That sets the prerequisites of *every* target to be *every* `*.c` file in the directory. That's not what you want. You want each target to have its own `.c` file as its prerequisite.

You want:

```
all: $(PRGS)

%: %.c
        $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $@.c -o $@
```

That being said make has a built-in rule for exactly that `foo.c` -> `foo` compilation so you should just use that. That rule uses the `$(CC)` and `$(CFLAGS)` variables. So just set those to what you want and you are done.

So this makefile should do what you want. (Note how I moved some arguments to `CFLAGS` instead of `CC`. `CC` should generally, to my knowledge, by the compiler itself and not any arguments.)

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -ansi -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -O3
PRGS := $(patsubst %.c,%,$(wildcard *.c))

all : $(PRGS)
```

Comment: To be clear, are you suggesting this change to my 'workaround' or the original? Making the change the 'workaround' actually tries to compile all.c into all. Changing the original doesn't quite clean up the redundancy.

Comment: wow! I can't believe I didn't see that. That is definitely what I was looking for. Thank you! :)